# Reading arduino response

Tags: android, arduino

I am writing the code to communicate with arduino. 
I am able to write the msg on arduino but I am not able to read the response.

I am writing this:

```
.....
    outputStream.write(msgBuffer);
    int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
   if(bytesAvailable > 0){
            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
            inputStream.read(packetBytes);
....
```

The variable bytesAvailable  is always 0.

Comment: The name of application.I changed it but I think it is not important.

Comment: Names have no output stream or input stream so i think kca was something different. Actually you made it even worse.